# How can I remove from a model after a $.draggable() drop in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I have two AngularJS controllers, a `List` of users and a `Trash` area.

The idea is that you could drag a user from the `List` into the `Trash`, and the `List` controller will remove that user from it's `$scope.users` array model.

I'm pretty close, I just don't know how to send the `user` object to remove from `$scope.users[]`.

I have a working JSBin here: (for some reason, it doesn't work when my browser is at 1920x1080; if you shrink your browser down a bit it should work.. weird)

http://jsbin.com/uMUfejeP/3/edit

As you can see, it calls the `list.deleteMe()` function, but I don't know how to send the object to remove. I tried using `ngValue` but that didn't seem to do much.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using jqueryUI, you can take advantage of the [droppable API](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/), specifically, the `drop` event.

```
element.droppable({
  //...
  drop: function(event, ui) {
     // handle the drop
  }
  //...
});
```

One way, and it's not necessarily the best way, is to use the `draggable` property of the `ui` argument.

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
  // this is how you get an angular scope from an element
  var friendScope = angular.element(ui.draggable).scope()
  // now, friendScope.friend is the friend you want to delete
}
```

The problem with this is that you start really tangling concerns together, but this should get you out of your immediate spot.

Here's your [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/AqitIFu/2/edit), refactored to have a `Friends` service and `Trash` service, and using this approach.

It would probably be better to wrap the drag and drop functionality in its own module and expose some directive APIs for using it. A quick google search for 'angular drag and drop' yielded [this project](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/), among others, that do just that.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that; that works perfectly. Is there any reason you wrote the `service` and the `directive`s strung together with the `angular.module()` function instead of broken out as separate functions like I had before? I see this way of writing Angular a lot, and wondering how standard it is.

Also, thanks for showing me the `angular.element.scope()` function, that seems very useful.

Either way I'll be studying your jsbin and refactor my project that way. Thanks for your time and the quality response.

Comment: If I were actually trying to restructure the code, I would have put the controller into the module as well. As a general rule of thumb, put everything into a module - it keeps the global namespace clear, and makes it a little nicer to know where things come from. You can still break things out syntactically: `var app = angular.module('app', []);` and then `app.controller(..), app.directive(..), etc.`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explaination!

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was just sending back the `user.user_id` and searching for a `User` object with the same `id`. It seems a bit inefficient; I'd love to just send back a reference to the `User` object and remove it from the array.

If anyone has an idea on how to do this, I'll accept their answer instead of my own.